# Resolving Different Values on "No" and Modal Close (X) in Ant Design 3x Modal Confirm

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

I'm using Ant Design 3X modal confirm for showing a confirmation modal in my React application. I need to resolve a Promise with different values depending on the user's interaction with the modal:

- Resolve with 1 when the user clicks "Yes."
- Resolve with 0 when the user clicks "No."
- Resolve with 2 when the user closes the modal using the "X" icon.

However, I've noticed that when I close the modal with the "X" icon, the onCancel function is called and resolves the Promise with 0. Here's my code:

```
Confirmation = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        confirm({
            title: `Message`,
            okText: 'Yes',
            cancelText: 'No',
            onOk: () => {
                resolve(1)
            },
            onCancel: () => {
                resolve(0)
            },
        });
    })
}
```

Is there a way to distinguish between closing the modal with the "X" icon and clicking "No" so that I can resolve the Promise with 2 when the modal is closed with the "X" icon?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behavior of resolving different values when the user clicks "No" or closes the modal with the "X" icon in Ant Design Modal Confirm by making a slight modification to your onCancel handler. Here's the updated code:

```
Confirmation = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        confirm({
            title: `Message`,
            okText: 'Yes',
            cancelText: 'No',
            onOk: () => {
                resolve(1); // Resolve with 1 when the user clicks "Yes"
            },
            onCancel: (close) => {
                if (close?.triggerCancel) {
                    resolve(2); // Resolve with 2 when the modal is closed using the "X" icon
                } else {
                    resolve(0); // Resolve with 0 when the user clicks "No"
                    close(true); // Close the modal
                }
            },
        });
    });
};
```

In this code:

- When the user clicks "Yes," the onOk handler resolves the Promise with 1.
- When the user clicks "No," the onCancel handler checks if close?.triggerCancel is true, indicating that the modal was closed using the "X" icon, and then resolves the Promise with 2. If it's false, it resolves with 0 (when the user clicks "No") and also closes the modal using close(true).

This modification ensures that you can distinguish between closing the modal with the "X" icon and clicking "No" and resolve the Promise accordingly.